# Replace lm with jsgf file in python

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

Using this pocketsphinx command  with python , how can i use **jsgf** instead of **lm** ? ( i have created my own model with arabic/french words and i don't know how to use it now with python ..)

```
speech = LiveSpeech(
verbose=False,
sampling_rate=16000,
buffer_size=2048,
no_search=False,
full_utt=False,
hmm=os.path.join(model_path, 'mymodel.ci_cont'),
lm=os.path.join(model_path, 'xxxx'), 
dic=os.path.join(model_path, 'mymodel.dict')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
jsgf=os.path.join(model_path, 'file.jsgf'),
```

instead of

```
lm=os.path.join(model_path, 'xxxx'),
```